# What inner tube size

Tags: innertube

I have a early 1960’s Schwinn Corvette with a tire size of 26 x 1 3/4 S7. I can find the tire replacement but not the inner tube replacement. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Look at "Related" along the right side of this page.

Answer (score 2):

Proper S7 571 tubes for this have existed, but you're fine using 559, ie anything that says "26 x 1.75" or covers it in a range.